# Printing strings and separating them with "\"

Tags: python

Can someone help me: I can't remove the spaces in my output. I'm using the `replace()` function, but it's not working:

```py
wor1 = str(input())
wor2 = str(input())

print(wor1,"\\",wor2.replace(" ",""))

if wor1 == wor2:
    print('Equal')
```

My custom input is:

```
hello
hello
and my output is showing:
hello \ hello
Equal
```

and the output should be:

```
hello\hello
Equal
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sep=''` in `print`. The default speratrator is `' '`. Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

```py
wor1 = str(input())
wor2 = str(input())

print(wor1,"\\",wor2, sep='')

if wor1 == wor2:
    print('Equal')
```

Comment: isn't `.replace()` redundant when using `sep=''`

Comment: No, the `separator` is placed during printing to the stdout.

Comment: I know but OP used them in a wrong way anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider concatenating the strings rather than passing them as separate arguments:

```py
wor1 = str(input())
wor2 = str(input())

print(wor1 + wor2)

if wor1 == wor2:
    print('Equal')
```

Another alternative would be using `join()`:

```py
wor1 = str(input())
wor2 = str(input())

wors = [wor1, wor2]  # could have even more, just increase the number of elements in the list

print(''.join(wors))

if wor1 == wor2:
    print('Equal')
```